# Calculating time intervals considering business days and 24x7

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgresql structure and data :

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
    entity_id INTEGER,
    type_de_demande TEXT,
    phase TEXT,
    time BIGINT,
    next_time BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO requests (entity_id, type_de_demande, phase, time, next_time)
VALUES
    (3402670, 'SUPPORTREQUEST', 'Log', 1684836635813, 1684836637569),
    (3402670, 'SUPPORTREQUEST', 'Classify', 1684836637569, 1684836638257),
    (3402670, 'SUPPORTREQUEST', 'FirstLineSupport', 1684836638257, 1685090241035),
    (3402670, 'SUPPORTREQUEST', 'Escalate', 1685090241035, 1685090241833),
    (3402670, 'SUPPORTREQUEST', 'Close', 1685090241833, NULL)
```

The objective is to calculate the time interval between "time" and "next_time" in business time (excluding Saturday and Sunday) and 24x7 time. Currently, I am able to obtain the correct interval for 24x7 time, but for the business interval, I am getting incorrect values.

Here is my SQL select query :

```
SELECT
    t.entity_id,
    t.type_de_demande,
    t.phase,
    bd.bus_interval,
    bd.interval_24x7,
    ts.start_ts,
    ts.end_ts,
    t.time,
    t.next_time
FROM requests AS t
inner join lateral (
    SELECT 
        to_timestamp(t.time / 1000)::timestamp      AS start_ts,
        to_timestamp(t.next_time / 1000)::timestamp AS end_ts,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)::int 
         FROM generate_series(to_timestamp(t.time / 1000)::DATE, to_timestamp(t.next_time / 1000)::DATE, '1 day')
         WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM generate_series) < 6
        ) AS bus_days
) AS ts ON true
inner join lateral (
    SELECT 
        ts.end_ts - ts.start_ts as interval_24x7,
        make_interval(0,0,0,ts.bus_days - 1) + ((ts.end_ts - ts.start_ts)::time)::interval  as bus_interval
) as bd on true
```

Result :

| entity_id | type_de_demande | phase | bus_interval | interval_24x7 | start_ts | end_ts | time | next_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3402670 | SUPPORTREQUEST | Log | {"seconds":2} | {"seconds":2} | 2023-05-23T10:10:35.000Z | 2023-05-23T10:10:37.000Z | 1684836635813 | 1684836637569 |
| 3402670 | SUPPORTREQUEST | Classify | {"seconds":1} | {"seconds":1} | 2023-05-23T10:10:37.000Z | 2023-05-23T10:10:38.000Z | 1684836637569 | 1684836638257 |
| 3402670 | SUPPORTREQUEST | FirstLineSupport | {"days":3,"hours":22,"minutes":26,"seconds":43} | {"days":2,"hours":22,"minutes":26,"seconds":43} | 2023-05-23T10:10:38.000Z | 2023-05-26T08:37:21.000Z | 1684836638257 | 1685090241035 |
| 3402670 | SUPPORTREQUEST | Escalate | {} | {} | 2023-05-26T08:37:21.000Z | 2023-05-26T08:37:21.000Z | 1685090241035 | 1685090241833 |
| 3402670 | SUPPORTREQUEST | Close | null | null | 2023-05-26T08:37:21.000Z | null | 1685090241833 | null |

Why does the `bus_interval` column have an additional day `{"days":3,"hours":22,"minutes":26,"seconds":43}` instead of the expected value of `{"days":2,"hours":22,"minutes":26,"seconds":43}`? Is there another method to calculate the interval between two Unix timestamps considering both business days and 24x7 time?

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axnWR8TUupXywi1ddHDHtX/0

Comment: Consider summer time and its double resp. 02:00 - 03:00 gap. Easiest to use UTC. But then the front-end code, programming language, needs to do locale conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your bus_days sub query should be like following. I have removed ::DATE cast and also including generate_series timestamp only when its less than or equal to t.next_time.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*)::int 
         FROM generate_series(to_timestamp(t.time / 1000), to_timestamp(t.next_time / 1000), '1 day')
         WHERE generate_series <= to_timestamp(t.next_time / 1000) AND EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM generate_series) < 6
        ) AS bus_days
```